How to enable CORS in Hapi (post version 17)
In pre-v18 of Hapi, enabling CORS was pretty straightforward:
const server = Hapi.server({
    port: 3000,
    host: 'localhost',
    routes: {
        cors: true
    }
});

With v18 the syntax for Hapi.server() changed and routes is no longer correct syntax.  However, it is not clear to me from the Hapi documentation what the new syntax should be for enabling CORS.
I've tried setting it in the options stanza for a specific route but that isn't working either - although it doesn't throw an exception.
 {
      method: "GET",
      path: "/getCountyByState/{state}",
      options: { cors: true },
      handler: async function (request, h) {
        request.log('error', 'Event error');
  }

If the Hapi docs showed a few examples this would not be an issue :-)

Digging deeper into the documentation - server.options.routes.cors is still valid for setting CORS at the server level.
